# How do I create an SNS subscription filter involving two attributes using the AWS CDK in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, subscription, aws-cdk

I am setting up our AWS infrastructure using CDK in Python.  I want to subscribe an sqs queue to an SNS topic using a filter when the id is in a range and the type is one of two types.  The filter should look like this:

{
  "id": [{"numeric": [">", 0, "<", 100]}],
  "type": ["foo", "bar"] 
}

This is what I have:

class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def **init**(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().**init**(scope, id,  **kwargs)

```
    queue = sqs.Queue(self, "MyQueue")
    snsTopic = sns.Topic(self, "MyTopic", display_name="My Topic")

    idMapping = {"id":  sns.SubscriptionFilter(conditions=[{"numeric": [">", 0, "<", 100] } ])}
    typeMapping = {"type" : sns.SubscriptionFilter(conditions=["foo", "bar"])}

    sub = subs.SqsSubscription(queue, filter_policy = idMapping)
    snsTopic.add_subscription(sub)
```

It seems to work if I set the filter_policy to either idMapping or typeMapping, but how do I do the AND of the two?

Comment: does it not work to `mapping = {"id": ...,"type" :...)}`?

Comment: Oh yes.  It is so simple.  If you put that as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just give one dict containing both keys

`mapping = {"id": ...,"type" :...)}`